# Генератор списков, как сменить значение в списке?

Tags: python, список

Как в списке `some_list` изменить значение `None` на `''`

```
some_list = ['текст',None,'ничего интересного']
none_elements = [ x=='' if x ==None else x for x in some_list]
```

Данный код выводит:

```
['текст', False, 'ничего интересного']
```

Как с помощью генератора списка получить:

```
 ['текст', '', 'ничего интересного']
```

Comment: `x==''` поменять на просто `''`, сейчас у вас результат такого сравнения выводится

Comment: @CrazyElf, этот вариант сработал :)

Answer (score 2):

```
res = ['' if x==None else x for x in some_list]
```